# Override DNS For Specific Domains Like A Hosts File, But Without Using Hosts file

Tags: perl, dns, lwp, lwp-useragent

I need to issue a series of parallelized web requests from the same server to a specific domain, but control what IP address these requests actually go to.  Originally, I came up with a scheme where I would request the IP I wanted specifically, and then manually set the `Host: www.example.com` header on the request, and use a series of handlers to make sure that redirects issued followed the same pattern.

This seemed to work for some time, but lately I've been having trouble with redirects to HTTPS.  The handshake will fail, and the request in turn.  <s>I have tried disabling SSL verification in a variety of ways, including:</s>

```
local $ENV{ PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME } = 0;
local $ENV{ HTTPS_DEBUG }                  = 1;

$ua->ssl_opts(
    SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file(),
    verify_hostname => 0,
    SSL_verify_mode => 0x00,
);

IO::Socket::SSL::set_ctx_defaults(
    SSL_verifycn_scheme => 'www',
    SSL_verify_mode => 0,
);
```

I have also tried using [LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts](http://search.cpan.org/~masaki/LWP-UserAgent-DNS-Hosts-0.05/README.pod) to solve the problem, but it persists.

**<edit>I should note that the reason why turning off peer validation for SSL is not solving the problem is likely because for some reason requesting this way is actually causing the handshake to fail, not failing on a validation point.</edit>**

One thing that works is making an entry in `/etc/hosts` to point the domain at the appropriate IP, however this is not practical, because I may need to run tens, or hundreds, of tests, in parallel, on the same domain.

Is there a way to emulate the functionality of adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` that does not involve requesting the IP specifically and overriding the `Host: ...` HTTP header?

#### EDIT: SSL Debug Info

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1914: new ctx 140288835318480
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:402: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:404: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:422: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:455: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:478: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:491: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:501: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:511: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:531: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:491: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1388: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:497: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1948: free ctx 140288835318480 open=140288835318480
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1953: free ctx 140288835318480 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1956: OK free ctx 140288835318480
```

And in the response I get:

> Can't connect to redacted.org:443
>
> `SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.`

It fails equally well on our server (using an older legacy version of Perl, which I will not disclose here as it seems irrelevant).

The server initially responds to a non-HTTPS request with a 301 redirect to the HTTPS site.  Then the failure occurs.  I will post reproducing code with the specific details of my request removed, but any site which redirects non-HTTPS traffic to HTTPS should suffice.

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw/ debug4 /;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts;
use HTTP::Request;
use Mozilla::CA;
use Data::Dumper;

LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->register_hosts(
    'recacted.org' => '127.0.0.1', # no I am not redirecting to loopback in reality, this is anonymized
    'www.redacted.org' => '127.0.0.1',
);

LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->enable_override;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts( SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() );

my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://redacted.org/');

my $response = $ua->request($request);

print $response->content; #Dumper ( $response->is_success ? $response->headers : $response );
```

Again, that is not the production code, just enough code to reproduce the issue.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with SSL verification, but moreover an inability to negotiate the request, presumably because `LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts` is doing exactly what I was doing: changing the request target to the desired IP, and then writing the `Host: ...` header manually.  Why this causes the SSL handshake to fail, I do not know.

On my local machine debugging

```
openssl version -a: 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION == 1.966
Net::SSLeay->VERSION == 1.72
```

On a server of ours

```
openssl version -a: 1.0.1t 3 May 2016
IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION == 1.76
Net::SSLeay->VERSION == 1.48
```

Comment: I would have thought that `LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts` was exactly the right tool. What went wrong?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what exactly with the handshake is failing. From what you've tried so far my guess is that it is not even related to the certificate validation and thus fiddling with it does not help. Please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 ...` to enable SSL debugging and also provide the versions of IO::Socket::SSL, Net::SSLeay and openssl you are using.

Comment: Please also provide information about the server setup you are using and what was changed on your client and server side setup which might be relevant to the failure. For example it might be that your problem is caused by changes on the server side or by upgrading to new openssl or IO::Socket::SSL versions and now you don't have any shared ciphers since the servers wants RC4 and newer IO::Socket::SSL have disabled this insecure cipher.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added the information you've requested.

Comment: I just found this link, perhaps this issue is rather old (and the solution to it also old, one would hope)? http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.libwww/1999/11/msg217.html

Comment: @Dereleased: The server is sending back an alert which means that it does not like the client. And this is even done before the certificate is send and before any HTTP is send, i.e. fiddling with certificate validation or HTTP headers will not help. My guess the problem is either that the server requires SNI extension or that the server requires some ciphers the client does not provide or that a very old server requires SSL 3.0 which is disabled in newer OpenSSL versions by default (i.e. in 1.0.2).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Did I mention the request succeeds if I override the ip using my `/etc/hosts` file?  How can I get this to behave the same way, but use the IP I prefer without having to write it into `/etc/hosts` (which makes it impossible to parallelize requests for multiple IPs but the same domain name)?

Comment: @Dereleased: In this case this sounds like a problem with SNI. Try to explicitly give `SSL_hostname` with the hostname of the server as argument in `ssl_opts`. The line about `not using SNI because hostname is unknown` should vanish then from debug output if done right.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Please post that as an answer so I can accept and upvote.  Edit: it worked flawlessly if that was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it works with an explicit `/etc/hosts` file but not with just replacing `PeerAddr` or using `LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts` this looks like a problem with the SNI extension. This TLS extension is used to provide the TLS server with the requested hostname (similar to the HTTP `Host` header) so that it can choose the appropriate certificate. If this SNI extension is missing some servers return a default certificate while others throw an error, like in this case.

The fix is to provide the hostname using `SSL_hostname` in `ssl_opts`. Such  fix could probably also help with `LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts`, i.e in [LWP/Protocol/https/hosts.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/MASAKI/LWP-UserAgent-DNS-Hosts-0.11/lib/LWP/Protocol/https/hosts.pm):

```
12    if (my $peer_addr = LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->_registered_peer_addr($host)) {
13        push @opts, (
14            PeerAddr          => $peer_addr,
15            Host              => $host,
16            SSL_verifycn_name => $host,
NEW           SSL_hostname      => $host,   # for SNI
17        );
18    }
```